# xcopy only copy subdirectories with their contents

Tags: windows, xcopy

As the title says...

An example:
I have these files & dirs:

```
c:\file.txt  
c:\a\somefile.txt  
c:\b\anotherfile.txt
```

And with some magic I want this structure on the destination:

```
d:\a\somefile.txt  
d:\b\anotherfile.txt
```

Can this be done with xcopy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes:

```
C:\> FOR /D %d in (*) DO xcopy /S /I %d d:\%d
```

- **/D** : Just directories
- **/S** : Copy subdirectories
- **/I** : Targets are directory (not file)

:-)